Linear Regression Adjustment Issue: Learning Rate vs. Equation Accuracy (Python)
I'm attempting to adjust the linear regression with a learning rate of 0.01. However, I'm encountering an issue where the line doesn't seem to adjust properly. Instead of following the expected path dictated by the learning rate, the line seems to randomly shift to different positions without proper alignment. I'm sure its not because of the learning rate, but rather the equation.
This is what I tried
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression, make_classification, make_blobs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random as rd

# 1. make_regression
x, y = make_regression(
  n_samples=100,
  n_features=1,
  noise=30
)

# 2. make_classification
train_x = x[:-20]
test_x = x[-20:]

train_y = y[:-20]
test_y = y[-20:]

# 3. make_blobs
def graph_linear_regression():
  # Plot the data
  plt.scatter(train_x, train_y, color='blue', label='Data')

  # Plot the linear regression line
  plt.plot(train_x, train_x, color='red', label='Linear Regression')

  # Add labels and title
  plt.xlabel('x')
  plt.ylabel('y')
  plt.title('Linear Regression')

  # Display the plot
  plt.legend()
  plt.show()

# 4. Calculate the error
def calculate_update_error():
  global m
  global b
  learning_rate = 0.01
  # Calculate Error
  # M = 1/n * sum(f(x) - y)
  # B = 1/n * sum(f(x) - y) * x

  M = 1 / n * np.sum(f(train_x) - train_y)
  B = 1 / n * np.sum(np.sum(f(train_x) - train_y) * train_x)

  m = m - learning_rate * M
  b = b - learning_rate * B

# Calculate linear regresion
# Step 1 - initialize

m = rd.randint(1, 100)
b = rd.randint(1, 100)
n = len(train_x)
learning_rate = 0.01

print(f"n: {n}")
print(f"m: {m}")
print(f"b: {b}")
print(f"learning_rate: {learning_rate}")

def f(x):
  return m * x + b

# Problem?
for i in range(n):
  calculate_update_error()
  print()

graph_linear_regression()

This is what im getting
enter image description here
Now, this is what im trying to obtain, this is using minimum square
enter image description here

The lines you've pointed out:
M = 1 / n * np.sum(f(train_x) - train_y)
B = 1 / n * np.sum(np.sum(f(train_x) - train_y) * train_x)

are incorrect because they involve operations between arrays of incompatible shapes.
y_train is a 1D array with shape of (80,) and f(x_train) is a 2D array with a shape of (1, 80). So f(train_x) - train_y will be an (80, 80) array which is not intended in this use case.
In addition, the term x_train should be multiplied when calculating the gradient of f respecting M not B.
You can calculate gradients by either transposing one of them:
M = 1 / n * np.sum((f(train_x) - train_y.reshape(-1, 1)) * train_x)
B = 1 / n * np.sum(f(train_x) - train_y.reshape(-1, 1))

or use For loops like this:
M = 1 / n * np.sum(np.array([(f(x_i) - y_i) * x_i for x_i, y_i in zip(train_x, train_y)]))
B = 1 / n * np.sum(np.array([f(x_i) - y_i for x_i, y_i in zip(train_x, train_y)]))

Moreover, a better range for initialization should be used. For example, use random.uniform for m and b like this:
m = random.uniform(-100, 100)
b = random.uniform(-100, 100)

